# pandas match dict 'else'

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a problem:

```
import pandas

new_dict={
    'a':1,
    'b':2,
    'else':4
}
df=pandas.DataFrame([['new1','a'],['new2','b'],['new3','c'],['new4','d'],['new5','b']],columns=['new','id'])
```

the df like this

```
    new id
0  new1  a
1  new2  b
2  new3  c
3  new4  d
4  new5  b
```

the result I wanted:

```
   new id
0  new1  1
1  new2  2
2  new3  4
3  new4  4
4  new5  2
```

I try to convert the dict to a dataframe and use the merge method. but the 'else' don't match:

```
import pandas

new_dict={'newid':['a','b','else'],
      'idd':[1,2,4]}
df2=pandas.DataFrame(new_dict,columns=['newid','idd'])
df=pandas.DataFrame([['new1','a'],['new2','b'],['new3','c'],['new4','d'],['new5','b']],columns=['new','id'])
```

I try use pandas merge method to solve this problem, but I don't know what next step I should do. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df.id = df.id.map(new_dict).fillna(new_dict['else']).astype(int)
print (df)
    new  id
0  new1   1
1  new2   2
2  new3   4
3  new4   4
4  new5   2
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df.id = np.where(df.id.isin(new_dict), df.id.map(new_dict), new_dict['else']).astype(int)
print (df)
    new  id
0  new1   1
1  new2   2
2  new3   4
3  new4   4
4  new5   2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` with a function as well.
I also use the dictionary you specified but accessed values via the `get` method in which you can specify a default value.

```
def new(x):
    new_dict = dict(a=1, b=2)
    return new_dict.get(x, 4)

df=pd.DataFrame([
    ['new1','a'],['new2','b'],
    ['new3','c'],['new4','d'],
    ['new5','b']],
    columns=['new','id'])


df.id = df.id.map(new)

print(df)

    new  id
0  new1   1
1  new2   2
2  new3   4
3  new4   4
4  new5   2
```